# Is there a way for Blazor webassembly .net6 to get wifi SSID

Tags: javascript, blazor-webassembly, browser-api

I am coding in blazor webassembly in .net6 and was trying out if I could get the user's wifi information such as ssid on any devices, However I could not find any information and I have tried to the network information API but no luck found.

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API*

Comment: If there is a way then it is about JS and Browser APIs. Use the right tags to get the right audience.